# How can I send and argument to a C code from a Python code

Tags: python, c, subprocess, output, stdin

I have a Python code that compiles and executes another C file. The thing is, how can I do to send arguments? The C code is a text processer, so it waits for text in order to process it and give an output. How can I declare the input so that the C program receives it and process it?

```
import subprocess  
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

print("This is read by py!")
subprocess.call(["gcc","main.c"]);
subprocess.call("./a.exe")
p = Popen(['main.c'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = p.communicate(input='div')[0]

print("Done")
```

Comment: That's what the `input=` argument to `p.communicate` is.

Comment: You probably want to do `Popen` on the _executable_ `./a.exe` and _not_ the _source_ file `main.c` And, you want to do that in lieu of: `subprocess.call("./a.exe")`